# use SqlRoleProvider in hiding/showing buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net, t-sql

I've finally made `SqlRoleProvider` work in my ASP.Net web application. I'm going to use it to filter webpage access in my system, i.e. only `Admins` only have access to the User Management page, `Makers` and `Approvers` only have access to the main functionality of the website, etc. **My question is, since `SqlRoleProvider` can be used to filter webpages, can it also be used to filter buttons on the same page?** I have a web page that both Makers and Approvers have access to, but in this case, only Makers should be able to see Edit and Delete Record buttons, and only Approvers should be able to see the Approve and Reject buttons.

**EDIT 1:**

this is what I have so far:

```
SqlRoleProvider fxSRP = new SqlRoleProvider();   


if ((fxSRP.IsUserInRole(fxUserName[0], "Approver")) == false)
{

    btnApproveTxn.Visible = false;
    btnRejectTxn.Visible = false;
```

I need to figure out how to get the username of the user who's currently accessing the webpages, so that I can put that in place of the fxUserName[0] which I hard-coded earlier just for testing.

Comment: of course you can do. Show us what attempt you have taken to achieve that ?

Comment: i have this: `if ((fxSRP.IsUserInRole(fxUserName[0], "Approver")) == false)`. I instantiated SqlRoleProvider earlier as `fxSRP`. I need to figure out how to get the username of the user who's currently accessing the webpages, so that I can put that in place of the `fxUserName[0]` which I hard-coded earlier just for testing.